# Is there a way (or tool) to convert games in PGN to notations like the one in the description?

Tags: database, visualization

Example:

White: Kd6, Rh6

Black: Kd8

1.?

**Background story:** I'm thinking of creating material for developing the visualization skills of my students. If I can convert easy problems to text notations and ask people to solve them without a chess board, I'm thinking it would be a good exercise for visualization in chess.

Comment: Do you really want to convert a pgn or rather just a FEN string?

Comment: I thought of converting a pgn database into such chess notations so that I can print them out.

Comment: This is not the way to practice visualization. It's best done with a chess board but without moving the pieces.

Comment: Jester asked because PGN describes an entire game, while FEN describes a particular position.

Comment: Thanks @dfan 
I hadn't considered FEN, but now I'm thinking that maybe I should find a way to convert a pgn to FEN -- just the starting positions with who should move and result, so that I can export and print them out as a material.

Comment: @overtheboard I'm experimenting! If you have any other ideas, do share them! Thanks.

Comment: @ArunJ If the starting position of a PGN file is not just the standard starting position of chess, it is specified as a FEN string.

Comment: Produce a standard chessboard image from the pgn and let them look at that?

Answer (score 2):

PGN is for game notation, i.e. the whole game. You can use the FEN notation by creating the position on chessvideos.tv FEN generator site and then use the code to input this into Fritz or your preferred software. Code is on the top right. `3k4/8/3K3R/8/8/8/8/8` is the code for the position you gave.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the answer, you can use [Fen2Ascii](http://www.wmlsoftware.com/download.html), a little program that converts pasted FEN lines into ASCII formatted text. From its website:

> r1bqk2r/pppp2pp/2n1pn2/5p2/2PP4/5NP1/PP1NPPBP/R2QK2R b KQkq - 0 7
>
> is changed to
>
> W-Ke1,Qd1,Ra1,h1,Bg2,Nd2,f3,Pa2,b2,c4,d4,e2,f2,g3,h2
>   B-Ke8,Qd8,Ra8,h8,Bc8,Nc6,f6,Pa7,b7,c7,d7,e6,f5,g7,h7    Black to move.